# How to identify an object in selenium where class name contains a space (like: 'uniqclass xyz') or multiple similar class names exist

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, firebug, firepath

Please see the HTML code below

```html
<div class="dgrid-content ui-widget-content" tabindex="0">

<div id="uniqName-36397" class=" dgrid default Item001">
<div id="uniqName-36780" class=" dgrid default Item003">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath. You can try:

```
"//div[starts-with(@id, 'uniqName-')]"
```

This will fetch all the elements whose `id` attribute value begins with `uniqName-`.

You can iterate over each element by using the following code:

```
IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[starts-with(@id, 'uniqName-')]"));
foreach(IWebElement element in elements) {
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jason, but it will return all elements where ID starts with 'UniqName..' but how to go on my corresponding ID to perform the action. lets say that there are 10 elements on page where ID starts with 'UniqName..'

Comment: @PankajDubey - You can iterate over it. If you want a specific `id` value then you can use `By.Id`.